# How to do WP_User_Query for Nested Array value Inside Nested Array field

Tags: wp-query, query, meta-query, user-meta, wp-user-query

i am still new in wordpress development and try to playing with WP_User_Query right now.

I have meta field, with this value:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'address' => 
    array (
      'street_1' => 'Street 1 String',
      'street_2' => '',
      'city' => 'SEARCH',
      'zip' => '',
      'state' => '',
      'country' => '',
    ),
  ),
)
```

What i am trying to do, i want to search / query user filtered by city using SEARCH keyword. How to achieve that using WP_User_Query?

Thanks

Comment: If you have all of this data in one meta field as serialized array in WP database, you cannot. If you want to enable the possibility of searching your posts by this criteria, you'll need to split this data and use several meta fields.

Comment: @Ivan Shatsky, that's unfortunate. So, what the nested limit that can still be queried? Thanks for your answer btw 

Comment: You cannot use `WP_Query` for searching values inside arrays at all. `WP_Query` is some kind of wrapper over raw SQL requests made to your database, and this array would be stored in a database as a serialized string: `a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:7:"address";a:6:{s:8:"street_1";s:15:"Street 1 String";s:8:"street_2";s:0:"";s:4:"city";s:6:"SEARCH";s:3:"zip";s:0:"";s:5:"state";s:0:"";s:7:"country";s:0:"";}}}`. Can you imagine an SQL query for searching inside such a data? Use a separate meta field for every value that you want to use as search criteria.